# Pandas: fill out missing months in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe contains zipcodes, months and the number of purchases up until that month.
However, some months are missing for some zipcodes. As you can see in the example below, the months March and April are not recorded for zipcode '2400'.

```
     Zipcode       Date              Cumulative purchases
0     9999    December 2018                     2
1     9999    January 2019                      2
2     9999    February 2019                     2
3     9999    March 2019                        3
4     9999    April 2019                        4
5     2400    December 2018                     2
6     2400    January 2019                      3
7     2400    February 2019                     4
etc
```

I would like to add these month records, by repeating the cumulative purchases
Ideally it would look like this:

```
     Zipcode       Date              Cumulative purchases
0     9999    December 2018                     2
1     9999    January 2019                      2
2     9999    February 2019                     2
3     9999    March 2019                        3
4     9999    April 2019                        4
5     2400    December 2018                     2
6     2400    January 2019                      3
7     2400    February 2019                     4
8     2400    March 2019                        4
9     2400    April 2019                        4
etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html) to expose the missing values :

```
#  pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn
df.complete('Zipcode', ('Date', 'Cumulative')).ffill()

   Zipcode      Date  Cumulative  purchases
0     9999  December        2018        2.0
1     9999   January        2019        2.0
2     9999  February        2019        2.0
3     9999     March        2019        3.0
4     9999     April        2019        4.0
5     2400  December        2018        2.0
6     2400   January        2019        3.0
7     2400  February        2019        4.0
8     2400     March        2019        4.0
9     2400     April        2019        4.0
```

Comment: that complete function link does not seem to work anymore. As of 2023/03/23 it is at https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit changed previous answer with removed `reset_index`, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and added missing datetimes up to `until` in [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), forward filling missing values and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) :

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = (df.set_index('Date')
        .groupby('Zipcode', sort=False)
        .resample('MS')['Purchase'].sum()
        .groupby(level=0)
        .cumsum()
        .unstack()
        )

until = pd.to_datetime('2019-04')

df = (df.reindex(pd.date_range(df.columns.min(), until, freq='MS', name='Date'), axis=1)
        .ffill(axis=1)
        .stack()
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index(name='Cumulative purchases'))

df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%B %Y')
print (df)
   Zipcode           Date  Cumulative purchases
0     9999  December 2018                     2
1     9999   January 2019                     2
2     9999  February 2019                     2
3     9999     March 2019                     3
4     9999     April 2019                     4
5     2400  December 2018                     2
6     2400   January 2019                     3
7     2400  February 2019                     4
8     2400     March 2019                     4
9     2400     April 2019                     4
```